# Centos 7 with window manager

Tags: linux, centos

I am using Linode as my Cloud hosting and I installed a minimal Centos 7 in my server. Everything is fine. I thought it was a minimal instalation but right after I install "firefox" (yum install firefox) and run it (firefox &) it work perfectly. It shouldnt work cause there should be no visual/graphic interface.

What is even more strange is that if I install vncserver in this server and use VNC Viewer I can see the firefox window displayed! So how does this happen? I wish my server had no visual interface so I could save memory and CPU.

Does anyone know how to remove this apparently "visual interface"?

Comment: are you being charged for RAM/CPU usage?  If not it probably will not make much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

As the user 'root', try editing your /etc/inittab file to use login mode 3.  Hence, the file entry will look as such.

`id:3:initdefault:`

You can always get back to the GUI (if you decide to later) by going to login mode 5.